# Tips for first time cyclist on 9W in NJ/NY

Tags: bikeroutes

Not sure I can find a group in my area that fits for me. Up until now I've been mainly sticking to local rides in areas without a lot of car traffic. Lately I've been riding more with destinations in mind. I've never taken a bike ride from the George Washington Bridge up 9W towards NY but I would like to.

I mapped out the ride on google maps and it shows that sometimes you ride against traffic and sometimes you ride on the side with traffic. Could someone explain why and where you switch or have a cue sheet? Couldn't find a cue sheet online and the navigation on my android phone doesn't seem to support cycling which has caused me some problems when I've tried to use it on rides.

Answer (score 1):

An additional resource is [Stava](http://www.strava.com/). You can join for free, and there is an Android app on the Google [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.strava).

To start planning your ride see [this Stava map](http://www.strava.com/segments/explore#location/George%20Washington%20Bridge/type/cycling/min/0/max/5/surface/undefined/center/40.894787,-73.910618/zoom/12/map_type/terrain); zoom for more detail. Maybe you'll need to have signed up to see it.

If you set up (or find a route) for your ride, you can download or print cue sheets like [this one](http://www.strava.com/routes/374616/cue_sheet).

There are several [Bicycles.SE](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) members with local knowledge; hopefully they'll post more explicit answers :-)

Comment: Is there any chance Stava has turn-by-turn navigation with voice prompts? Been looking for one for android with no luck. Tried using the regular navigation for another ride and it wanted to put me on a major interstate. Think I found a hack for it though.

Comment: Haven't tried that on Strava. Another option is Endemondo. Again I haven't used navigation on it, but it does have voice progress updates, so ... maybe ...

Comment: @Sproxno Are you setting the Google Maps app to bicycling?

Comment: @Andrey yes I am but when I switched to Navigation it didn't seem to pick the bike route. Maybe did something wrong will try it again.

Comment: @Andrey Just checked again and it seems Navigation can now follow the bike route. Not sre what the problem was before. Still looking for actual advice as I have some concerns due to the number of reports I read each year about accidents on this road.

Comment: @sproxno There are no turn-by-turns in strava's app as of October 2015.  However I put my phone in a top-tube bag with a clear window, and I connect it to a USB battery, and set the display lock to 30 minutes.  It will run strava for 12+ hours and can display my planned route.  

The only downsides are strong sunlight makes the screen a bit hard to read, and the phone is somewhat vulnerable to damage.   I use an $89 samsung disposable phone for this reason.